# Find word in string from list Python

Tags: python, string, list

Hello I try to output some word what i will found in some string:

exaple:

```
string="Lampa tylna lewa + prawa AUDI A-6 '04-'08"

def brand (string):
    car_array = ['Audi', 'Bmw', 'Chevrolet', 'Citroen', 'Dacia', 'Daihatsu', 'Dodge', 'Fiat', 'Ford', 'Honda',
                 'Hyundai', 'Isuzu', 'Iveco', 'Jeep', 'Kia', 'Land', 'Mazda', 'Mercedes', 'Mitsubishi', 'Nissan',
                 'Opel', 'Peugeot', 'Porsche', 'Renault', 'Seat', 'Skoda', 'SsangYong', 'Subaru', 'Suzuki', 'Toyota',
                 'Volkswagen', 'Volvo', "Vw", "Citroën", "Tesla", "Jaguar", "Mini", "Saab", "Lexus", "Infiniti", "Maserati",
                 'Chrysler', 'Alfa', 'Aston']

    if any(word.upper() in string for word in car_array):
        marka="found"
        return marka
```

Its work but how I can return this found word?

Like

```
"AUDI"
```

for exaple

Comment: With `any`, you can't. Why not use a regular `for word in car_array:` loop?

Comment: Are you looking for only 1 word? What if there are 2 or more brands in given `string`? Don't you want to find them both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any, you can't. Using a regular `for word in car_array`: loop

```
def brand(string):
    car_array = ['Audi', 'Bmw', 'Chevrolet', 'Citroen', 'Dacia', 'Daihatsu', 'Dodge', 'Fiat', 'Ford', 'Honda',
                 'Hyundai', 'Isuzu', 'Iveco', 'Jeep', 'Kia', 'Land', 'Mazda', 'Mercedes', 'Mitsubishi', 'Nissan',
                 'Opel', 'Peugeot', 'Porsche', 'Renault', 'Seat', 'Skoda', 'SsangYong', 'Subaru', 'Suzuki', 'Toyota',
                 'Volkswagen', 'Volvo', "Vw", "Citroën", "Tesla", "Jaguar", "Mini", "Saab", "Lexus", "Infiniti",
                 "Maserati",
                 'Chrysler', 'Alfa', 'Aston']
    for word in car_array:
        if word.lower() in string.lower():
            found_word_index = string.lower().find(word.lower())
            return string[found_word_index:found_word_index+len(word)]

string = "Lampa tylna lewa + prawa AUDI A-6 '04-'08"
print(brand(string))
```

output:

```
AUDI
```

Comment: The output is bad. `Audi` was NOT in the string. `AUDI` was.

Comment: What if the brand name is not present as `upper` in `string`? You won't find it. You search for `word.upper() in string`...

Comment: Updated @Aaron_ab.